# Functions with integral as an infinite sum of its own values

Tags: functions, definite-integrals, summation, functional-equations

Just curious, how can we figure out functions satisfying the following condition?

$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f(n)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$

I got one, f(x) = x<sup>-x</sup> (I'll post my solution on request)

Are there more functions satisfying the same condition?

Answer (score 1):

Why, there are many. $f(x)$ that equals $1$ for $x\in[0,1)$ and $0$ elsewhere will do. $f(x)=e^{-ax}$ with carefully chosen constant $a\approx0.930821$ will do. There are more such functions than you seem to think, and more than you will be thinking *after* reading these words, and even more than that.

[**Sophomore's dream**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) (as your example is commonly called) has been famous for quite a while due to the nature of the function, which would not let us to come up with a closed form either for the sum or the integral, and yet the two are equal. Remove the function; what remains is trivial. It does not even make sense to look for other such functions.

Really, take an *arbitrary* function with finite integral on $[0,1]$. Extend it with arbitrary values at 3, 4, 5, and so on, just make sure that the sum is finite, too. Now assign $f(2)$ so as to make the sum equal to the integral. You're done. Oh, and you may define the function in an arbitrary way at the remaining non-integer points outside $[0,1]$, if you would like, or just leave it like that. Doesn't sound very exciting, does it?

So it goes.